# Separating EditText and TableRows in Layout

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, textview

I'm having trouble moving my TextView up an away from all of my TableRows. They both share a parent TableLayout.

Here you can see the TextView highlighted with the blue perimeter box. How the heck do I move this towards the top/center of the screen and AWAY from the table rows/buttons??
[image]

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#8CD11D"

android:gravity="bottom"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.retrocalc.MainActivity" >

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="55sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


</RelativeLayout>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clearb"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="CLR"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteb"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="DEL"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/oneb"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/twob"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/threeb"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/subtractb"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="-"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fourb"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="4"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fiveb"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="5"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sixb"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="6"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addb"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="+"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sevenb"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="7"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/eightb"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="8"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nineb"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="9"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/divideb"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="/"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/zerob"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/decimalb"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="."
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/multiplyb"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="x"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/equalsb"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="="
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your TextView out from TableLayout, wrap your TableLayout in another Layout like a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout and the add that TextView in the main layout like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8CD11D">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="55sp" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.retrocalc.MainActivity" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CLR"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deleteb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="DEL"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/oneb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/twob"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/threeb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="3"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/subtractb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="-"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fourb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="4"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fiveb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sixb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="6"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="+"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sevenb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="7"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eightb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="8"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nineb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="9"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/divideb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="/"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zerob"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/decimalb"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="."
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/multiplyb"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="x"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equalsb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="="
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works much better. I still have some formatting issues to work out so if I stumble again I will comment again here. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8CD11D"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:textSize="55sp" />
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="CLR"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deleteb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="DEL"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/oneb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/twob"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/threeb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="3"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/subtractb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="-"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fourb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="4"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fiveb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sixb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="6"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="+"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sevenb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="7"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eightb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="8"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nineb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="9"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/divideb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="/"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zerob"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/decimalb"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="."
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/multiplyb"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="x"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equalsb"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="="
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
    </TableLayout>
```